# BlueJ picture in jar

Tags: image, swing, jar, embedded-resource, bluej

I've just finished a GUI project and I want to figure out how to get an image that I reference into the completed jar file. As of right now I just reference it as:

```
try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("<name>.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

in my project.
What do I need to do to get it to show up in my program?

Comment: This is the last thing I need to do, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

By the time of Jarring, those resources will have become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

### General Tip

Change code of the form

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    // ..
```

To:

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! 
    // ..
```

Comment: Yeah I eventually figured that out. Thanks though!